# Problems with STAGE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, error-handling, stage, stagewebview

I am pretty new to as3 programming. This forum helped me already a lot, but now I have a problem where I don't know how to get on. So this is my first Post on stack overflow.com.

I need StageWebView for displaying a PDF-document. After several hours, I was successful. I created the code in a new blank document and tested it step by step.

```
This is my code:

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage; 

public function StageWebViewExample(pdfdoc:String, xpos:Number, ypos:Number, breite:Number, hoehe:Number) 
{
    var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
    webView.stage = this.stage;   //PROBLEM LINE
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle (xpos, ypos, breite, hoehe);           
    var file:String = pdfdoc;
    var pdf:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(file);
    webView.loadURL(pdf.nativePath);            
}

StageWebViewExample("test.pdf", 200, 200, 600, 1200);
```

After testing, I copied the code in my existing flash-document. (The code in a several as-File and the "calling" (StageWebViewExample("....) in the existing flash-document...)

But now the code does't work anymore and there are the following Errors: 
- 1119 Access of possibly undefined property stage...
- 1059 Property is read-only.
--> Both Errors referring to the same line I marked in the Code.

Has anyone an idea why it don't work?
I would really appreciate a good hint!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for question is your actions ;) You moved code from the Document Class, in another one, that don't have access to the stage as instance property. I mean `this.stage`.
Pass Stage also to the method StageWebViewExample, function signature will look like:

```
public function stageWebViewExample(stage: Stage, pdfdoc:String, xpos:Number, ypos:Number, breite:Number, hoehe:Number):void {
    var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
    webView.stage = stage;   
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle (xpos, ypos, breite, hoehe);           
    var file:String = pdfdoc;
    var pdf:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(file);
    webView.loadURL(pdf.nativePath);            
}
```

Working AIR example:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.StageWebView;

    public class StackOverflow extends Sprite {

        public function StackOverflow() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        }

        private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            start();
        }

        private function start():void {
            showWebViewAt(this.stage, "http://www.iab.net/media/file/VASTv3.0.pdf", new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth * 0.5, stage.stageHeight));
        }

        private function showWebViewAt(stage:Stage, path:String, frame:Rectangle):void {
            var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
            webView.stage = stage;
            webView.viewPort = frame;
            webView.loadURL(path);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reaction! Basicly you just replaced this.stage with just stage.

Comment: No, I didn't just replace, check function signature, last element of it. You should pass reference on the Stage to method.

Comment: ah. now I see. I think i can even imagine what you meant. but the second error remains. (1050 - protected...)

Comment: is it possible that it has something to do with public, private and protected attributes?

Comment: Paste somewhere fullstack of error: http://pastebin.com/ or show how do you call function with StageWebView

Comment: it's error in StageWebViewExample.as "1059: Property is read-only" at line 19 (webView.stage = stage;). The function is called with StageWebViewExample("test.pdf", 200, 200, 600, 1200); in main flash document. it seems that webView.stage is copy protected, but i can't figure out why.

Comment: If you call from Document Class, like you said 'main flash document'. So you still do it in old way. Rewrite your function as provided. And call it `StageWebViewExample(this.stage, "test.pdf", 200, 200, 600, 1200);`

Comment: ok. i just tried it exactly as you said. but then the old two errors occure. i tried a combination of your solution and the one of nicolas siver - but it won't work. it's frustrating :-(

Comment: i tried your example. but i think, i am doing something wong. to try it, i first created a new flash file (adobe air 4.0 and as3) and saved it. as code i used stop(); & showWebViewAt(); in the blank flaw document. Then i created a AS-File and saved it to the same location. as a name for the as-file i used "StackOverflow.as". But when i test your example finally, 3 erros occur.